# Java: Casting Object to a generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java when casting from an Object to other types, why does the second line produce a warning related to the cast, but the first one doesn't?

```
void a(Object o) {
  Integer i = (Integer) o;
  List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) o;
}

/*Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<Integer>*/
```

Comment: The second line produces a warning because only generics generate such a warning.  The first contains no generic, hence no warning.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's because the object won't *really* be checked for being a `List<Integer>` at execution time due to *type erasure*. It'll really just be casting it to `List`. For example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("x");
Object o = strings;

// Warning, but will succeeed at execution time
List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>) o;
Integer i = integers.get(0); // Bang!
```

See [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more info, particularly the [type erasure section](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure).

Answer (score 9):

Jon's answer is the right one, but occasionally you can't get around that warning (like when you're working with a legacy API). In those cases you can suppress the warning like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) someApiThatReturnsNonGenericList();
```

Answer (score 9):

For clarity, let me slightly rewrite the examples...

I would say, the **cruxial difference** between:

```
void a(Object o) {
  Integer i = (Integer) o;
  ...
}
```

and

```
void a(Object o) {
  List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) o;
  ...
}
```

is that, given that **there is a type-error**, the first cast will always **immediately throw** a RuntimeException (specifically, a ClassCastException) when executed.

While the second one **might** not -- as long as the input parameter o is any kind of `List<?>`, execution will just proceed, **in spite** of an incorrect cast.

Whether the code will somewhere **later** throw an exception or not, depends upon what you do with the list.

But regardless, an Exception might **not be thrown at the line where the cast was made**, but somewhere else (which might be a difficult bug to trace down) or not at all.

That's what I understand, is the reason the compiler-designers considered a warning appropriate in the second case only.

Comment: The first *will not* always throw a CastClassException.  The incoming object could very well be an `Integer`.  The first line MIGHT throw an exception, just as the second might if `o` is not a `List`.

Comment: @Hot Licks : yeah, that's why I wrote "given that there is a type-error" above -- I even put in bold ;)